# Folder Content type and Document Set content type in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have this requirement to add default folders to a document set, that is when a new document set is created using a specific content type it produces few folders by default.  when I try to add Folder Content type to Document Set Content type SharePoint does not seem to allow this type of operation, only document and other content types are allowed.

any ideas how to work around this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Folders are not supported in Document sets:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603637%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can auto generate the folders by accessing the Document Set settings on the Manage Content Type panel for the Document Set content type. Create the folders in the default content section by using the default Document Content Type, providing a file name and adding a dummy WORD Document. In addition, you can generate some placeholder content types with a parent type of document (just generate the extra content types and add them to your Document Set Content type making them available by adding them to the available content types in the top section and then clicking the link in the default content section to add them) to generate additional folders by providing a folder name in the folder column and a dummy WORD document. Just generate

Comment: Hint: you want your answer to be helpful to human readers. Therefore **form** matters. Like using punctuation and formatting. Your answer is simply not human readable.